# Treeview dependent on Combobox

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a problem regarding TReeview and combo box.
Problem:
I have a Treeview with Parent and Child Nodes. 
I have a drop box or  a combo box. Whenever I select a value from the combobox it should automatically select the same node in the treeview list.

Please give me suggestions on how to perform this.

This is what I tried so far:

```
protected void nav_dd_parent_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       nav_treeview.selectedvalue = nav_dd_parent.selectedvalue.tostring();
}
```

But it  says that nav_treeview is read only and it can not be assigned any values.

Comment: Do you have any code to show us? What have you tried thus far? Also, please do not use the ASP tag. I'm pretty sure that you mean ASP.NET since you've referenced the `TreeView` control, but the ASP tag has a big disclaimer telling you to not use it.

Comment: What have you done to try to solve the problem so far? Can you share some of the code that isn't working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried the following to give you an example:

HTML:

```
<asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server">
</asp:TreeView>
<br />
<br />
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Code Behind:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            Dictionary<string, Int32> myList = new Dictionary<string, Int32>();
            myList.Add("Text1", 1);
            myList.Add("Text2", 2);
            myList.Add("Text3", 3);
            myList.Add("Text4", 4);
            myList.Add("Text5", 5);

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Int32> s in myList)
            {
                this.TreeView1.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(s.Key, s.Value.ToString()));
                this.DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem(s.Key, s.Value.ToString()));
            }
            foreach (TreeNode tn in this.TreeView1.Nodes)
            {
                tn.ChildNodes.Add(new TreeNode("Hello World"));
                tn.Collapse();
            }
        }
    }

    protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.DropDownList1.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            foreach (TreeNode tn in this.TreeView1.Nodes)
            {
                if (tn.Value == this.DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value)
                {
                    tn.Selected = true;
                    if (tn.ChildNodes.Count > 0)
                    {
                        tn.Expand();
                    }
                }
                else {
                    tn.Collapse();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Hopefully this is what you needed. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You will want to set `AutoPostBack` on the `DropDownList` and add an `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event handler. Or, you could try and write it all in javascript to avoid the post back.

Comment: autopostback does not work. Everytime I select a value it refreshed and selects the default value and the event is not fired